# How could I proof that $f \in C^{1}(A,R)$ with $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is locally Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I thought that maybe I can use the mean value theorem in several variables in this way, $\forall \ convex \ set \ B \in A$:

$$|F(x)-F(y)| = |(\nabla F(y+\tau(x-y)),(x-y))_{2}| \leq ||(\nabla F(y+\tau(x-y))||_{2}||(x-y)||_{2}$$
$\forall x,y \in B$, with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I can't move on..

Comment: Is there any more information about $A$? Is it connected, open, etc?

Comment: You are getting there! Since $\nabla F$ in your displayed equation is presumably continuous, its norm will attain its maximum over any compact ball.

Comment: Yes, A is open. I thought so about the closure of the ball, but are we sure that the closure of every ball i take will be contained in A? If yes, for which reason? I have no hypothesis on the closure of every ball :( ....

Comment: If $B(x,r) \subset A$ then $\overline{B(x, {r \over 2})} \subset A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another straightforward way might be application of Taylor's
theorem:

$f(y)-f(x)= \int_0^1 {\partial f(x+t (y-x) \over \partial x} (y-x) dt$.

Pick some $a \in A$ and some ball $B(a,r)$ whose closure is contained in $A$ and let
$L = \sup_{x \in B(a,r)} \| {\partial f(x+t (y-x) \over \partial x} \|$, then the above gives
$\|f(y) - f(x)\| \le L \|y-x\|$ for $x,y \in B(a,r)$.